# Trying and failing to use BOOL in iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, ios, boolean, ios6

I have the following method where I am trying to determine of someone is associated with a practice.  Coming from C# this seemed like the right way to do this, but I'm getting some warnings/errors here.

```
- (BOOL) isAvailablePractice:(NSString*)practiceId
{
    BOOL *check = NO;

    for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < [self.practices count]; i++)
    {
        EHRXOption *o = [self.practices objectAtIndex:i];
        if([o.id isEqualToString:practiceId])
            check = YES;
    }

    return check;
}
```

On the line I set check = YES I get the following warning

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'BOOL *' (aka 'signed char *') from 'signed char';
```

on return check I get this error

```
Incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'BOOL *' (aka 'signed char *') from a function with result type 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char'); dereference with *
```

The way I understand this error, and I could be wrong is that if I put a * in front of return *check it would actually be returning a new value and not the one I've been working with.

I'm really not understanding how Objective C uses the BOOL value.

Comment: Even worse. You're not understaning how C works. I'd suggest you to master C before making *The Very Most Bestest iPhone App Ever (TM)...*

Comment: Sidenote 2: you could optimize this loop by removing the break and simply retuning YES straight from the for loop. The code currently wastes processor time.

Comment: If you allow me to ask another stupid question, if I return YES from the loop, that will break out of it as well, or do I need to add in a break?

Comment: if you return from a function that exits the function scope completely. It immediately jumps back to the caller. (Excercise: from this description, try to answer it yourself.)

Comment: I understand what you mean.  Do I still leave a return NO; after the loop should it get all the way through and not find one?  I'm assuming yes.

Comment: as the function returns a value (it's not declared as `void`), you'll still need to return NO at the end, else it will invoke undefined behavior and possibly returning garbage. You wouldn't need that final return if the function returned `void`.

Comment: If I have it return void can I still call it this way?
if([user isAvailablePractice:p.id])

Comment: C# is much more strict about this sort of thing and wouldn't allow me to return a value if I use void.

Comment: That's my last question on this, promise.

Comment: no, you couldn't. But really, read a C tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> BOOL *check = NO;

is incorrect change it to

> BOOL check = NO;

Comment: Well that fixed it.  Is that because the property is never used outside the scope of the method?  I've seen stuff like this before but never quite understood why.

Comment: No its because BOOL is still a primitive. If you look at the source, its a typedef of a bool. simples!

Comment: Coming from a world like java or C# or ruby or basically most languages, C is going to trip you up repeatedly. You need to study pointers. In other words C is basically a handy way to write assembler.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a pointer.

Just `BOOL check = NO;`

Answer (score 1):

You want `BOOL check` rather than `BOOL *check`. The first is a BOOL value; the latter is a pointer to a BOOL. Since you're not dealing with any BOOL addresses in your code there, a pointer is not the right type.